# Why is there such a big difference in the transfer rates of the Java FTP Clients

Tags: java, apache, ftp

maybe someone can answer me that question. During my recent works I noticed that my application (which downloads updates via FTP) was really slow when used with Linux. I develop that stuff on a Mac so I didn't notice that issue earlier, because the download speed didn't feel very low under Mac OS. But when moving to Linux the application behaved really different.

The FTP server (Pure FTP running on Ubuntu Server) is connected to the same LAN as the clients, so internet speed issues do not come into account. Because of the low performance I changed the Apache FTPClient to edtFTPj/Free. The differences are still remarkable but acceptable. As a test case I downloaded always the same file which had a size of about 30 MB. Then I checked the ftp server log to find out about the transfer rate.

See for Yourself. The VMWare mentioned runs on the Mac. The Java is a Oracle Java 1.7 unless noted otherwise.

### Apache Commons Net 2.3

The code looks like this

```
  FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
  ftp.connect("srv0006");
  ftp.login("anonymous", "asd");
  ftp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
  File target = new File("/tmp/pub.tar");
  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(target);
  ftp.retrieveFile("/pub.tar", fos);
  fos.close();
```

Here are the results from the ftp log

#### Mac OS started from IntelliJ Idea

```
downloaded  (30452736 bytes, 21200.67KB/sec)
```

#### Mac OS started from shell

```
downloaded  (30452736 bytes, 21471.75KB/sec)
```

#### Windows 7 (in VMWare)

```
downloaded  (30452736 bytes, 65243.15KB/sec)
```

#### OpenSuse running Oracle Java (in VMWare)

```
downloaded  (30452736 bytes, 5274.56KB/sec)
```

#### OpenSuse running OpenJDK (in VMWare)

```
downloaded  (30452736 bytes, 7663.68KB/sec)
```

#### Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS

running on another PC connected with Gigabit Ethernet to the same LAN. Other Ubuntu Machines behaved exactly the same way. I quit the transfer after 20 Minutes. See the transfer rate.

```
downloaded  (7077888 bytes, 6.10KB/sec)
```

### edtFTP4j 2.4.0

After this, I moved to edtFTP4j. The results were much better.

```
  FileTransferClient ftp = new FileTransferClient();
  ftp.setRemoteHost("srv0006");
  ftp.setUserName("anonymous");
  ftp.setPassword("asd");
  ftp.connect();
  ftp.downloadFile("/tmp/pub.tar", "/pub.tar");
  ftp.disconnect();
```

The results changed remarkably:

#### Mac OS started from IntelliJ Idea

```
downloaded  (30452736 bytes, 109431.60KB/sec)
```

#### Mac OS started from shell

```
downloaded  (30452736 bytes, 110333.66KB/sec)
```

#### Windows 7 (in VMWare)

```
downloaded  (30452736 bytes, 91318.64KB/sec)
```

#### OpenSuse running Oracle Java (in VMWare)

```
downloaded  (30452736 bytes, 89312.46KB/sec)
```

#### OpenSuse running OpenJDK (in VMWare)

```
downloaded  (30452736 bytes, 89041.05KB/sec)
```

#### Ubuntu 12.10 (in VMWare)

```
downloaded  (30452736 bytes, 81154.99KB/sec)
```

#### Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS running on i5 Notebook, Wifi (50 MBit/s)

```
downloaded  (30452736 bytes, 2883.84KB/sec)
```

#### Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS running on i5 Notebook, Gigabit Ethernet

```
downloaded  (30452736 bytes, 93822.44KB/sec)
```

#### Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS

running on the PC mentioned earlier (the one with the 6.10 KB/sec tx rate)

```
downloaded  (30452736 bytes, 11633.38KB/sec)
```

I don't understand this. Who has a clue whats going on here ?

Bye, Torsten...

Answer (score 1):

There's too much going on to pinpoint it from some code.

It could be anything from your default network packet size (MTU), your hardware infrastructure, your JVM, your OS configuration, etc..

You need to play with lots of little things at the higher level.  Things like checking your MTU size on the hardware/OS level and correspond that to the default settings for the API's socket creation.  Does your infrastructure buffer or have window scaling or do automated virus checking.

I believe Net Commons buffer size defaults to 1024, you can play with that.

Beyond that, you need to drop down into the sniffer and see what's going on.  Could be a switch isn't configured correctly and works better with one API vs. the other.

Wish I could give you a better answer, but when it comes to networking performance, it's really a field of study in and of itself...

Comment: Mike is right.<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14000341/why-is-ftp-upload-slow-in-java-7" >This</a> shows some uploading speed problems.
Firewall can be an issue.I am not sure but java 7 has to do something with it.Did you try downloading with java 6? I am trying with Java Ftp alternatives and will get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

One culprit here is the socket send and receive buffer sizes on the different platforms. On Windows these are set ridiculously low at 8k, which drastically limits TCP throughput. Some windows server versions set these to enormous values; don't ask me which. Unix and Linux platforms have sane values around 43-48k.

Comment: Which explains the results how? Unix and Linux performed much worse than Windows in this experiment

Answer (score 0):

On many systems, there will be also a great difference between the passive and the active modes of FTP; especially when the server admit only one mode and the client try to use the other one by default.  If I remember correctly, the active mode is slightly faster than the passive mode but using a forbidden mode could easily slow down the transfert by more than a hundred or a thousand times; if not's simply blocking out.

Even if both modes are permitted, a firewall can frequently slow down the passive mode while leaving untouched the active mode (or is it the inverse?).

Answer (score 0):

I speculate the real answer is that no one has developed a fast copy command.

To have "ultimate copy/transfer" command, it would need to actively monitor things and adapt to the environment.

eg. copy(ref,ref) .. to make this fast, you can't use C for starters, you need to use something like a dynamic language that has option for C-performance. Few if any such languages exist.

the "ref" is a reference to anything and the copy command is JIT to machine specific branch that selects appropriate path based on the source and target.

So depending on what the ref's end up being at runtime, the actual command could be anything between adaptive network transfer that attempts multiple routings *to* memcpy *to* just adding a new reference (if src is immutable and target is in the same process and src accessible to it).